# character to date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

What is the error in below SQL:

```
select to_Date(substr('2/22/2015 9:20:06 AM',1,9),'mm/dd/yyyy','DD-MON-YY')  from dual
```

I am getting the following error:

> ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function error

But `select substr('2/22/2015 9:20:06 AM',1,9) from dual` shows `2/22/2015`. I want to convert this as date.

Answer (score 2):

> to_Date(substr('2/22/2015 9:20:06 AM',1,9),'mm/dd/yyyy','DD-MON-YY')

Break the query into individual parts and then understand.

**substr** and **to_date** are the two functions being used.

1. Extracting the required substring, **substr('2/22/2015 9:20:06 AM',1,9)**
2. Applying `TO_DATE` over the output of step 1, **TO_DATE(substr('2/22/2015 9:20:06 AM',1,9),'mm/dd/yyyy')**.
3. And, that's it.

So, in your posted query, `'DD-MON-YY'` format mask is not required at all.

Also, what you are trying to achieve is equivalent to:

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE('2/22/2015 9:20:06 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))
```

**TRUNC** removes the time portion from a **DATE** type.

Alternatively,

You could use the **[ANSI TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)** literal:

```
TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '2015-02-22 09:20:06')
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the third parameter from your `TO_DATE` method:

```
select to_date(substr('2/22/2015 9:20:06 AM',1,9),'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
```

This is the `nlsparam` (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)).