# SQL oracle error 12702. 00000 - "invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an error while running this query :

```
select a.date, e.date, x.rlv, e.rlv
from data_1 a
inner join data_2 e on e.date =  (select to_char(to_date(x.date,'yyyymmdd','yyyymmdd') 
    - INTERVAL '3' month,'yyyymmdd') from data_2 x where x.rlv=e.rlv)
;
```

I got this error :

> `12702. 00000 -  "invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function"` 
> `*Cause: An unknown parameter name or invalid value is specified in a NLS parameter string`

Do you have any ideas ? thanks in advance

Comment: It tells you that `'yyyymmdd'` isn't a valid NLS parameter. And the use of `to_char()` and `to_date()` suggests that you're using the wrong data types for dates, some `varchar2` or similar. Fix your schema and use an appropriate type like `date` and you don't have to pull such stunts in the first place.

Comment: @gatoo93 Post it as an answer please, and mark as solved. Note that Littlefoot answers more precisely to your question about why there is an error.

Comment: What data type is the column `x.date`?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747882/character-to-date-in-oracle-sql ?

Comment: I dont think its a duplicate. Its DATUM (DATS) data element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main problem with it is - as @sticky bit commented - that you're dealing with strings that represent date values. Wrong choice, switch to `DATE` datatype if possible.

Other than that, your code doesn't work because you misused syntax. Here's how (I modified column name from `date` - which is reserved for datatype - to `col`):

```
Your: to_char(to_date(col, 'yyyymmdd', 'yyyymmdd') - interval '3' month, 'yyyymmdd')
Mine: to_char(to_date(col, 'yyyymmdd') - interval '3' month, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Compare and see the difference.

Because, if you "fix" it, `interval` works just fine so, if you want, you can switch back to it from `add_months`:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '20210622' from dual)         --> today's date, 
  3  select to_char(to_date(col, 'yyyymmdd') - interval '3' month, 'yyyymmdd') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------
20210322                                     --> 3 months earlier

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello : 
 `to_char(to_date(col, 'yyyymmdd') - interval '3' month, 'yyyymmdd')`
 > 01839. 00000 -  "date not valid for month specified"

Comment: Which value did you pass for COL? Oracle expects a string in format I posted: YYYYMMDD. If it was e.g. 20212306 (changed MM and DD values), there's no "23rd" month in a year and you'd get such an error.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, the value for col is values from col itself, so a date in format YYYYMMDD as it used in SAP (oracle db). I take the same column and i substr 3 months thats it.

Comment: Well, error is pretty much clear. You passed an invalid value for **month** to the function with that (YYYY**MM**DD) format and Oracle was unable to convert it to a valid date value.

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for your answer. I find the solution by using add_monts : `(select to_char(add_months(to_date(x.date,'yyyymmdd'),-3), 'yyyymmdd')`  not sur its highly optimised but it works at least